# ¿Cómo se usan los símbolos "«" y "»", es decir, las comillas angulares, latinas o españolas?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, citas

Cuando leo artículos en Internet y estos contienen citas, normalmente están rodeados de esos símbolos.

¿Se puede escribir este símbolo con el teclado? ¿Tienen algún significado más allá del estético o estilografico?

¿De ser así, cuándo es apropiado usarlas, en contraste con las comillas comunes?

Comment: I think they are called guillemets and searching for that plus ypur OS should help. Many fo the hits will be in French, but not all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72714/discussion-on-question-by-pipe-como-se-usan-los-simbolos--y--es-decir-l).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estos símbolos se llaman comillas angulares, latinas o españolas.

Tal y como se indica en el artículo de la Wikipedia [*comillas* sección *Informática*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comillas#Inform.C3.A1tica), se consiguen de la siguiente forma:

| símbolo | Windows | Linux | Macintosh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| « | <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 174 | <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> | <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd> (es decir, `´`) |
| » | <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 175 | <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> | <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>ç</kbd> |

En cuanto a su uso, es el prioritario a la hora de citar. Como explica el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas:

> [**comillas**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SSTAZ5sDyD6h59vijX). 1. Signo ortográfico doble del cual se usan diferentes tipos en español: las **comillas angulares, también llamadas latinas o españolas (« »)**, las inglesas (“ ”) y las simples (‘ ’). Las comillas inglesas y las simples se escriben en la parte alta del renglón, mientras que las angulares se escriben centradas. En los textos impresos, se recomienda utilizar en primera instancia las comillas angulares, reservando los otros tipos para cuando deban entrecomillarse partes de un texto ya entrecomillado. En este caso, las comillas simples se emplearán en último lugar: *«Antonio me dijo: “Vaya ‘cacharro’ que se ha comprado Julián”»*. Las comillas se escriben pegadas a la primera y la última palabra del período que enmarcan, y separadas por un espacio de las palabras o signos que las preceden o las siguen; pero si lo que sigue a las comillas de cierre es un signo de puntuación, no se deja espacio entre ambos.

Es decir que tenemos tres tipos diferentes de comillas, cuyo uso prioritario es como sigue:

- comillas angulares, también llamadas latinas o españolas (« »)
- comillas inglesas (“ ”)
- comillas simples (‘ ’)

Para una explicación más exhaustiva (en inglés) puedes consultar [Quotation mark usage in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/934/1674).