# Are apostrophe quotes (", ') more correct or are angular quotes («, ») more correct for Castilian Spanish?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, puntuación, citas

This is just a curiosity of mine, and I'm also wondering if there are regional differences for use of different types of quotation marks (not correct but an example: Puerto Rico uses `«»` while Venezuela uses `""`).  For Castilian Spanish in Spain in particular, what is the more correct form to use (or at least most common)?

---

Esto es solo una de mis curiosidades, y también me pregunto si existen diferencias regionales para el uso de diferentes tipos de comillas (no es correcto, pero es un ejemplo: Puerto Rico usa `«»`, mientras que Venezuela usa `""`). Para el español castellano en España en particular, ¿cuál es la forma más correcta de usar (o al menos la más común)?

Comment: Quite answered in [Quotation mark usage in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/934/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui not really, I'm asking about regional differences with Spain in particular.

Comment: Para mí ver las angulares le da al texto un toque más formal y pulido. Las redondas, aunque pudiesen hacer tenido algún uso autóctono en el pasado, hoy me huelen pestilente y fétidamente a anglicismo :-)

Comment: jstowell Do you want to change the question to ask about what actual usage is and whether that differs within Spain to make your question more distinct from the one @fedorqui linked to?

Comment: @mdewey sure, I will sometime soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrés' answer shows the way quotes are used in legal, official Spanish, and that's useful in certain contexts like law-writing or in court judgements. However, in my experience, the most commonly used quotation marks in informal Spanish are the English ones (""). In my many years of being a Spaniard, never have I seen anyone use the latin quotation marks («») and very rarely the simple ('') marks in everyday online conversations and informal emails.

Comment: You're right @Alejandro Lorente Pons, anyway, the text I quoted says: "En los textos impresos..." in general, it says nothing about legal texts. But as you very well say, and also in my experience, and 'being a Chilean' «...the most commonly used quotation marks in informal (and also at formal) Spanish are the English ones ("")». Nevertheless, the question title specified: «...more correct for Castilian Spanish?», even though, later at the development of the question, you can find "...(or at least most common)."

Comment: That's correct, @AndrésChandía, and the fact he said "o al menos, la más común" is what motivated me to write my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> comillas. 1. Signo ortográfico doble del cual se usan diferentes tipos
>   en español: las comillas angulares, también llamadas latinas o
>   españolas (« »), las inglesas (“ ”) y las simples (‘ ’). Las comillas
>   inglesas y las simples se escriben en la parte alta del renglón,
>   mientras que las angulares se escriben centradas. En los textos
>   impresos, se recomienda utilizar en primera instancia las comillas
>   angulares, reservando los otros tipos para cuando deban
>   entrecomillarse partes de un texto ya entrecomillado. En este caso,
>   las comillas simples se emplearán en último lugar: «Antonio me dijo:
>   “Vaya ‘cacharro’ que se ha comprado Julián”». Las comillas se escriben
>   pegadas a la primera y la última palabra del período que enmarcan, y
>   separadas por un espacio de las palabras o signos que las preceden o
>   las siguen; pero si lo que sigue a las comillas de cierre es un signo
>   de puntuación, no se deja espacio entre ambos.

From: signos ortográficos: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=qXGSxldBKD6hqrTMMo

COMILLAS: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SSTAZ5sDyD6h59vijX